# JAVA java.lang.reflect.Constructor cannot call Date constructor

Tags: java, date, constructor, reference

receiving "java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception" calling instance of date(String) constructor.

code:

```
Constructor constr = fieldType.getConstructor(String.class);
if (constr != null) {
    val = constr.newInstance(val.toString()); // here is exeption
}

 fieldType = java.util.Date;
 val.getclass() = java.sql.Date,
 val.toString() = 2014-05-19
 constr [is not null] = java.util.Date(java.lang.String);
```

Maybe someone can help  me with solution, how to call constructor properly?

Comment: Seems you are trying to convert a `java.sql.Date` into a `java.util.Date`. This is not necessary as `java.sql.Date` is a sublass of `java.util.Date`

Comment: yes, but i my situation, I can receive different types, not only Date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor of `Date` throws an `Exception` because `Date(String)` expects the `String` parameter to be in a specific format and the `String` you pass to it is in a different format.

When using reflection if the constructor throws an exception, `Constructor.newInstance()` will wrap it and throw an `InvocationTargetException` which is what you get.

The required format for `Date(String)` is for example:

```
Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT
```

So you need to pass a date string in this format if you want `Date(String)` to work and not throw an Exception.

You can find more info on the required format in the javadoc of [Date.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) because the constructor calls this to parse the `String` parameter.

Comment: +1 moreover: the constructor of `java.util.Date` which accepts a `String` is deprecated.